# Multiple Submenus Each with Total Item Count

Tags: jquery, foreach, count, navigation, counting

I've started designing this menu and realized it deemed a little more challenging then expected. I'm trying to get the total item count of each submenu - *html example of one of my submenu structures below. If I included them all it would be too long*.

On the navigation menu, I would like to have the count beside the submenu on the right (see image). Currently I have an "x" there through the css ".accordion-item::before { content: "x" }". Ideally, I'd like to keep it this way hoping that I can get the count as a pseudo element.

**[My CodePen.](https://codepen.io/svpasch/pen/jOmOrGR?editors=0011)**

**Image Reference:**
[image]

**HTML:**

```
<ul id="navigation" class="drawer-navigation">
  <li id="menu-item-" class="menu-item menu-item-parent">
    <a class="accordion-item" href="https://www.google.com/">Photography</a>
    <ul class="submenu">
      <li id="submenu-item-" class="submenu-item">
        <a href="www.google.com">Weddings</a>
      </li>
      <li id="submenu-item-" class="submenu-item">
        <a href="www.google.com">Engagements</a>
      </li>
      <li id="submenu-item-" class="submenu-item">
        <a href="www.google.com">Anniversaries</a>
      </li>
      <li id="submenu-item-" class="submenu-item">
        <a href="www.google.com">Collaborations</a>
      </li>
      <li id="submenu-item-" class="submenu-item">
        <a href="www.google.com">Lookbooks</a>
      </li>
      <li id="submenu-item-" class="submenu-item">
        <a href="www.google.com">Family</a>
      </li>
      <li id="submenu-item-" class="submenu-item">
        <a href="www.google.com">Couples</a>
      </li>                                   
    </ul>
  </li>           
</ul>
```

**CSS:**

```
.menu-sidebar ul.drawer-navigation li.menu-item-parent a:not(ul.submenu li a)::before {
  content: "×";
  display: inline-block;
  positiion: relative;
  float: right;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: 22px;
  transform-origin: center;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transition-propery: transform;
  transition-duration: 600ms;
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.16, 1, 0.19, 1);
}
```

**JS:**
Currently just gets the total count of all submenu children.

```
$(document).ready( function() {
  
  var $countSource = $("#navigation");
  $countSource.each( function() {
    var $countElements = $("li.menu-item-parent ul").children().length;
    console.log($countElements);
  });
  
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to affect the pseudo `content` variable is to utilize it as a [css3 variable (custom property)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties). Unlike regular pseudo CSS rules (which are not part of the DOM and therefore cannot be manipulated with javascript)...

> Custom properties are ordinary properties, so they can be declared on
> any element, are resolved with the normal inheritance and cascade
> rules, can be made conditional with @media and other conditional
> rules, can be used in HTML’s style attribute, can be read or set using
> the CSSOM, etc.

I adjusted the css rules. You can use `>` to indicate top-level elements only so you don't have to use `:not`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#navigation > li > a").each(function() {
    let len = $(this).parent().find('.submenu').children().length;
    $(this).css('--content', `'${len}'`);
  });
});
```

```css
.menu-sidebar {
  width: 200px;
}

.menu-sidebar ul.drawer-navigation>li.menu-item-parent>a:before {
  content: var(--content, "g");
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  vertical-align: middle;
  /* font-size: 22px;
transform-origin: center;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transition-property: transform;
  transition-duration: 1600ms;
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.16, 1, 0.19, 1);*/
}

.submenu {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='menu-sidebar'>
  <ul id="navigation" class="drawer-navigation">
    <li id="menu-item-" class="menu-item menu-item-parent">
      <a class="accordion-item" href="https://www.google.com/">Photography</a>
      <ul class="submenu">
        <li id="submenu-item-" class="submenu-item">
          <a href="www.google.com">Weddings</a>
        </li>
        <li id="submenu-item-" class="submenu-item">
          <a href="www.google.com">Engagements</a>
        </li>
        <li id="submenu-item-" class="submenu-item">
          <a href="www.google.com">Anniversaries</a>
        </li>
        <li id="submenu-item-" class="submenu-item">
          <a href="www.google.com">Collaborations</a>
        </li>
        <li id="submenu-item-" class="submenu-item">
          <a href="www.google.com">Lookbooks</a>
        </li>
        <li id="submenu-item-" class="submenu-item">
          <a href="www.google.com">Family</a>
        </li>
        <li id="submenu-item-" class="submenu-item">
          <a href="www.google.com">Couples</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>

    <li id="menu-item-" class="menu-item menu-item-parent">
      <a class="accordion-item" href="https://www.google.com/">Fashion</a>
      <ul class="submenu">
        <li id="submenu-item-" class="submenu-item">
          <a href="www.google.com">Lookbooks</a>
        </li>
        <li id="submenu-item-" class="submenu-item">
          <a href="www.google.com">Family</a>
        </li>
        <li id="submenu-item-" class="submenu-item">
          <a href="www.google.com">Couples</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Firstly, thank you for your help. :) Maybe I should have clarified, but the HTML format I'm using is meant to resemble that of WordPress's. The preference around the pseudo element wasn't for any other reason other than I had my styling set in a way that worked with what I was doing. Though I do like the idea of using prepend and I am open to other ways! I used the ":not" because if not, it still targets the submenu "a" child. Apologies if this is all amateurish, it is exactly that as I'm trying to learn.

Comment: @Samantha - I adjusted the code. Turns out you can get to the pseudo 'content' property through javascript, in a special way. Take a look

Comment: Ahhh, yes! Thank you, this is exactly what I had in mind. I tried looking for something along the lines of this but I guess I was describing the wrong thing. Brilliant, thanks again!